# Remove colon from CTP UI "Singular Label"

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy

How can the colon be removed or changed from the Custom Post Type UI/Taxonomies/Singular Label? This colon shows up in my page title in Wordpress and looks like this "Recipes for: Dinner". Thank you!